# MSI BIOS won't recognize my Ubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation, grub

I have just bought a new MSI laptop that has Windows 10 pre-installed. I have two devices, /dev/sda and /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc has my Windows 10 install. Also, there is a partition on /dev/sdc for the Windows boot manager.

/dev/sda is the target for my Ubuntu 17.10 installation. I manage to install Ubuntu with no problems. But I haven't been able to get the MSI AMI BIOS to recognize or boot into the GRUB loader.

I've told the Ubuntu install to load the GRUB boot manager into /dev/sda and tried a number of different methods, but so far, nothing has worked. The BIOS only recognizes the Windows boot manager and when rebooting, automatically starts Windows 10.

What I want is for the BIOS to load the grub boot manager and allow me to boot Ubuntu or Windows as I desire.

Comment: Have you tried telling the zbIOS to boot in legacy rather then UEFI mode?

Comment: some MSI laptop has RAID features. RAID drivers for MSI laptop (e.g. GT series) works only for windows based.